# reset values for a variable in r, big dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to find a short way of writing a new variable condition on another variable. more specifically, have assume variable "x" has 5 categories for each letter A to G, i.e `A1,A2,...,A5, B1,B2,...,B5,...,G5` that is 35 categories in total and want to create a new variable "y" with integers from 1 to 35 condition on the variable "x".

this is what I did

```
y <- revalue(df$x, c("A1"="1","A2"="2","A3"="3","A4"="4","A5"="5",                                                               "B1"="6","B2"="7","B3"="8","B4"="9","B5"="10",
"C1"="11","C2"="12","C3"="13","C4"="14","C5"="15",
"D1"="16","D2"="17","D3"="18","D4"="19","D5"="20", ...))
```

Comment: What's `revalue` and `df`? Please include all additional packages. Also add wanted output.

Comment: Look into the `car` package, specifically the function `Recode()`.

Comment: `as.integer(factor(df$x))` should be sufficient since you want to encode lexical sorted categories.

Comment: @Roland can you be more specific how to code it? I'm new to r

Comment: `df$y <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$x))` should do it. It's basically the same as @Roland suggested. Note that this only works if the categories of your `x` variable are sorted in the way you need them.

Comment: I don't know how I could be more specific since you can literally copy my code and use it.

Comment: @Lap, what you suggested is no different from what I did. thanks anyway

Comment: @Roland, thank you. your suggestion worked.

Comment: @Erick Yeah, just noticed I misunderstood your question. At least with the `paste` approach, you wouldn't need to write out the recoding by hand. Glad that Roland's approach worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the comments:

In the scenario that your `x` categories are sorted exactly the way you want to enumerate them, use `as.numeric(as.factor())`:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(x = as.vector(sapply(LETTERS[1:7], paste0, 1:5)))

# new variable
df$y <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$x))
# note that you'd need to wrap it in as.character() if you want your numbers to be characters, 
# not integers
```

If your data is unsorted, you can use `car::Recode()`.

```
# install package if not already present
install.packages("car")

# new variable
df$z <- car::Recode(df$x, paste(paste0("'", levels(df$x), "' = '", 1:35, "'"), collapse = "; "))
# if you want your numbers to be integers, not characters, use this for the paste0():
# paste0("'", levels(df$x), "' = ", 1:35)
```

Output:

```
> df
    x  y  z
1  A1  1  1
2  A2  2  2
3  A3  3  3
4  A4  4  4
5  A5  5  5
6  B1  6  6
7  B2  7  7
8  B3  8  8
9  B4  9  9
10 B5 10 10
11 C1 11 11
12 C2 12 12
13 C3 13 13
14 C4 14 14
15 C5 15 15
16 D1 16 16
17 D2 17 17
18 D3 18 18
19 D4 19 19
20 D5 20 20
21 E1 21 21
22 E2 22 22
23 E3 23 23
24 E4 24 24
25 E5 25 25
26 F1 26 26
27 F2 27 27
28 F3 28 28
29 F4 29 29
30 F5 30 30
31 G1 31 31
32 G2 32 32
33 G3 33 33
34 G4 34 34
35 G5 35 35
```

Object classes for the example code:

```
> sapply(df, class)
        x         y         z 
 "factor" "numeric"  "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Roland this code should do it:

```
# create your data frame, note that the variable automatically becomes a factor.
df <- data.frame(x = sort(paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:7],5), 1:5)))
str(df)

# Returns the factor level as an integer
df$y <- as.integer(df$x)
```

A note of caution when working with factors is that you should check that your levels are in the right order (A1 -> 1, A2 -> 2, etc.).